# A ListView with only one column is showing its items in two columns

Tags: c#, listview

I have a column of four values (depending on number of attached screens on the users's computer). I am trying to use a ListView as I've found an example where I can grey out the unavailable screens.

However the list of four items is being shown in two columns like this:

Screen 1      Screen 3

Screen 2      Screen 4

I have tried changing the width of the column and the control, but without success.

WHY?

I was thinking that maybe the first column is a header column so have tried adding two columns and setting the first one's width to zero. But it's still the same.

```
            lvScreens.Columns.Add("Col", 0, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
            lvScreens.Columns[0].Width = lvScreens.Width - 4;
            lvScreens.FullRowSelect = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)  // I'm limiting the LV to 4 rows
            {
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem("Screen " + (i + 1).ToString());
                lvScreens.Items.Add(lvi);
                if (i < Screen.AllScreens.Count())
                {
                    lvScreens.Items[i].ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
                    lvScreens.Items[i].Selected = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    lvScreens.Items[i].ForeColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
                    lvScreens.Items[i].Selected = false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: It's not in a right mode. You need to switch to details mode.

Answer (score 5):

`ListView` control in winforms is a [wrapper](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListView.cs,683) over [winapi listview control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/create-a-list-view-control). This control intended to be used for windows file explorer and utilize easy switching between multiple views: two icons (big and small) views, list and details.

It seems you have it currently in wrong view (not sure which one, list?).

```
Screen 1 Screen 3

Screen 2 Screen 4
```

Simply set [ListView.View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.view) to `Details` mode to see *classic* `ListView` with multiple column headers (for each column you have actually added).

```
[Col]
Screen 1
Screen 2
Screen 3
Screen 4
```